# How to select unique strings from a concat of characters

Tags: r

I have some columns stored in a dataframe that have the following schema when I call a specific row:

```
str(df[5,9]) #Output: chr "bike,bike,car"
df[5,9] #Output: "bike,bike,car"
```

I am trying to find the distinct strings in each row in my dataframe. So the output that I am expecting is: "bike,car"

Similarly, when I call df[5,10], I get: 9,9,10. I would like to only have: 9,10

Is there any way I can find distinct on these strings/integers?

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can loop through the columns, do a split at the `,` and get the unique elements and `paste` it together

```
df[] <- lapply(df, function(x) sapply(strsplit(as.character(x), ",\\s*"), 
                               function(y) toString(unique(y))))
```

Comment: Thanks for response. I am getting this error: Error in strsplit(x, ",\\s*") : non-character argument. Do the columns need to be of a specific datatype for this to work? I figured since there are regular expressions it would make sense to leave it as type character.

Comment: @rmahesh  Fixed it.  It is because you have `factor` columns.  You can convert by wrapping with `as.character`